# How to add a database to visual studio 2010 Solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I want to ADD a database of sql server to Database project which is included in a visual studio Solution. Please Help it out.

Comment: who has created problem for me after downvoting this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a project on visual studio
2. Open server explorer click on 'connect to database' button, popup window will appear, type your server name in drop down.
3. Select your desired database and click okay. Visual Studio will add that database to your project.

Answer (score 1):

To create a project and a database file

1. Create a Windows Forms project that's named SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.

See [Creating Solutions and Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zfzh36t7(v=vs.110).aspx).

2. On the menu bar, choose Project, Add New Item.

The Add New Item dialog box appears so that you can add items that are appropriate in a Windows Form project.

3. In the list of templates, scroll down until Service-based Database appears, and then choose it.
4. Name the database SampleDatabase, and then choose the Add button.

The Data Source Configuration Wizard opens.

5. On the Choose a Database Model page, choose the Dataset icon, and then choose the Next button.

On the Choose Your Database Objects page, no database objects are available because the database is new.

6. Choose the Finish button to create the database and dataset and add them to the project.

and for more details please [clikc here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Open Solution Explorer.
>      Click on **App_Data**-> **Add**-> **New Item...**
> 2. In Add New Item window, Click on **SQL Server Database**.
>      Give a name to database at 
>      bottom of window database_name.mdf (like employeeDb.mdf). 
>      Click **Add**